# How to target div class within form

Tags: html, css, wordpress

```
<div class='ur-form-row'>

<div class="ur-form-grid ur-grid-1"

style="width:99%">

<div class="ur-field-item field-user_login">

<p class="form-row validate-required" 
id="user_login_field" data-priority=""><label 
for="user_login">Username <abbr class="required" 
title="required">*</abbr></label><input data-rules="" 
data-id="user_login" type="text" class="input-text input- 
text ur-frontend-field " name="user_login" id="user_login" 
placeholder=""  value="" required="required" data- 
label="Username" /></p>                                                          
</div>
```

I want to apply css `border-radius` to this class but it doesn't work

Tried all the options above such as:

.ur-form-row {border-radius: 20px;}

Comment: What is the `border` value?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You won't be able to apply a `border-radius` to an element which doesn't have a `border`. :)

Comment: Ok. I mean where do I find that info? Page is https://adsler.co.uk/dating/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding border before radius to the element

```
.ur-form-row input {
border:1px solid black;
border-radius: 20px;
}[it works fine check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrWq4.png)
```

Comment: Thanks but that just adds a border to the form as a whole and applies 20px border-radius to it. What I want is each individual input box to have 20px border-radius.

Comment: input { border-radius: 20px; }

Comment: try this                                                        
    input.ur-form-row input {
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius: 20px;
    }

Answer (score 0):

give border and border-radius to input-text class

```css
  .input-text  
  {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 26px;
  }
```

```html
<div class='ur-form-row'>

<div class="ur-form-grid ur-grid-1"

style="width:99%">

<div class="ur-field-item field-user_login">

<p class="form-row validate-required" 
id="user_login_field" data-priority=""><label 
for="user_login">Username <abbr class="required" 
title="required">*</abbr></label><input data-rules="" 
data-id="user_login" type="text" class="input-text input- 
text ur-frontend-field " name="user_login" id="user_login" 
placeholder=""  value="" required="required" data- 
label="Username" /></p>                                                          
</div>
```

Comment: please check the output in snippet and let me know if that is how you want

Answer (score 0):

here it is. just add this CSS to end of your style and add "makeRadius" to your input class.

```css
.makeRadius {
  border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}
```

```html
<input data-rules="" 
data-id="user_login" type="text" class="input-text input- 
text ur-frontend-field makeRadius" name="user_login" id="user_login" 
placeholder=""  value="" required="required" data- 
label="Username" />
```

Comment: OK then change .makeRadius to #user_login. it's Done!

Comment: That's so great, and it works, but i want all the boxes to be changed and that just changes user login

Comment: then you can replace #user_login with just "input" like this : input {border-radius:} or use .inpute-text